# SalesForce: How can I link a custom object field to a value Account record

Tags: salesforce, lookup

I am trying to find a solution of how to lookup a value on the Account Object and place it in a field on a record of a Custom Object.

Details below:

Objects 
**Accounts/ Organizations** - This contains information on different projects supported by my origination. Key fields of note: **Project Name(text)** and **Account Balance(text)**. There around 100 unique records in this object These field are manual led created.

**Regrant Request**   - This object contains records that are generated via web form that the projects fill out to receive payment for expenses related to their project. Each Regrant Request record also contains the **Project Name**(text) **Account Balance** .

Desired Result:
 When a new Regrant Request record is generated from the web form, it will take the value of the Project Name, match it with a record in the Accounts/Organization object.  Once the link has been made, I would like to take the value of the  Account Balance in the Accounts/ Organizations Object and copy to the Regrant Request record.

The problem that I am trying to solve is that in order a project to be paid the amount of money they request in the regrant request, they have to have enough funds.  It would be great if I did not have to leave the regrant request record to find this value.

I know that I have to tie each regrant request record to an account id.  That is stright forward but I am stuck on how to then get a value of field for said account id and then copy to a custom object.

any ideas would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to use zapier to do a search of the account object using the value of field inputted via the online form.  So cool !